# Find any control and put value to a Textbox Line

Tags: vb.net

With this code, the information will be sent in several textboxes. I want to be sent only in the textbox line, with the name Textbox3.Lines(i), so I tried this code.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 100
    Dim firstBoxList = TxtIntDraws.Lines(i).Split(",").ToArray
    Dim secondBoxList = TxtIntDraws.Lines(i + 1).Split(",").ToList()
    Dim intersectionList = firstBoxList.Intersect(secondBoxList)
    Dim Line = TxtIntDraws.Lines(i)
    For Each str As String In intersectionList
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        'inside the loop
        sb.AppendLine(str & ",")
        'and after the loop
        'This will prevent the textbox from having to repaint on every iteration
        TextBox3.Text = sb.ToString
    Next
Next
```

This code does not work because it only shows a value, not all, practically resets and displays the last value found.

Comment: Not sure why you have `For i As Integer = 1 To 100`. Anyway, use `TextBox.AppendText([Some String])` to append to the existing text. Setting the `.Text` property, you're of course overwriting what's already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to add to the TextBox with each iteration. Just store all the strings as you iterate to 100, then update the TextBox at the end.

```
Dim intersectionList As New List(Of String)()
For i As Integer = 1 To 100
    Dim firstBoxList = TxtIntDraws.Lines(i).Split(",")
    Dim secondBoxList = TxtIntDraws.Lines(i + 1).Split(",")
    intersectionList.Add(String.Join(", ", firstBoxList.Intersect(secondBoxList)))
Next
TextBox3.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, intersectionList)
```